# How to Post values outside the form in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to post values outside the form in php , How to do it

Here is my sample code

```
<input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" />
<input type="hidden" id="testvalue" name="testvalue"/>
<?Php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) { ?> 
     <form action='some_url'>
         <input type="text" value="dynamic_value" name='testname'>
      <select name="testselect">
  <option value="<?php echo $dynamicvalue[$i]?>"><?php echo $dynamicvalue[$i]?></option>
        </select>
    <button class="btn btn-primary book_now" type="submit">BookNow</button>

     </form>
  <?php } ?>
```

i need to post all input values above the form also,since i cannot use that input field inside the loop, i want id to be unique so i cant use inside

any other option available to post all data

Comment: Are there going to be 5 forms? Or just one form?

Comment: in loop form will be there , there will be 5 forms

Comment: What's this $dynamicvalue for? Also what's this input... value="dynamic_value" for? Please explain clearly what you're trying to achieve

Comment: you can't post values of the field which is not in the form tag...., but if you use ajax to submit form then u can achieve this.... and another thing is, why you cant take this fields in form tag ?? Is there any specific reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var test = $('#test').val();
        var testvalue = $('#testvalue').val();
        $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="test" value="'+test+'">');
        $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="testvalue" value="'+testvalue+'">');
        return true
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add input fields into for-loop

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) { ?> 
    <form action='some_url'>
        <input type="text" value="dynamic_value" name='testname'>
        <select name="testselect">
            <option value="<?php echo $dynamicvalue[$i]?>"><?php echo $dynamicvalue[$i]?></option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-primary book_now" type="submit">BookNow</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="test" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testvalue"/>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```